# JSON array is returned as single line and goes off screen. Need to split array into each row returned by query

Tags: arrays, json, foreach, split

With the following script, i have returned a JSON array which represents over 1000 rows from a database query.

```
`echo "<h2>Just an array of rows...</h2>";
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
$data[] = $row;
}
var_dump(json_encode($data, TRUE));`
```

However the array which is returned is a single line and goes off screen before the third row and therefore missing over 1000 records. I need to separate this array by each row (so split at each closing curly brace e.g. "}").

The currently returned JSON is as follows:

```
`'[{"Client_Desc":"Jaguar","Parent_Entity_Name":"Jaguar UK Region D","Entity_Name":"Guy Salmon     Jaguar (Thames     Ditton)","trackbacknumber":"8446628899","external_reference":"C8420","effective_start_date_time":"07\    /25\/2011 20:54:48","effective_end_date_time":"01\/01\/3000 00:00:00"},    {"Client_Desc":"Triumph","Parent_Entity_Name":"South","Entity_Name":"Hughenden M40     Ltd","trackbacknumber":"8446628893","external_reference":"160032","effective_start_date_time":"04\/29    \/2013 07:51:02","effective_end_date_time":"01\/'... (length=295125)`
```

Thank you for your time and all help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? That's how you'd go about converting an array to JSON, and it's a JSON array of objects (which is the same as a PHP array of associative arrays)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? JSON is a string representation of an object, array or other datatype. You explicitly converted your array to JSON and now you want to convert it back? What is the point in this? Do you want to have the PHP $data array transfered to the client to access it as a javascript array? Then you need to use 

var data = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

Comment: Where the JSON output is currently a single mass line. I want it divided by each row returned by the query and maintained as JSON. It's currently not readable because it just ends with "..." i need all data to be readable for the end user. My final target is to wrap this in a SOAP/WSDL service but would like to just return all the data for now. Is this better to understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
Use json_decode($data, true). This will provide an associative array.
```

Comment: Hiya. I need to maintain the output as a JSON array but currently does not fit on the screen as it is a single line. I wish to divide this array by each row returned by the query. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting. Open with Notepad++ and then Edit->Word wrap.

Comment: i'm in sublime text and word wrap was already set to automatic?

Comment: All done on my own. I had to specify the the content type in the content head i.e. application/json. And also used echo rather than var_dump. see below:

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo(json_encode($data, TRUE));

Answer (score 0):

The content header needed to be specified as json. This was achieved with the following:

```
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`
```

Plus instead of var_dump, echo was used which returned the entire json object. This is demonstrated below:

```
`echo(json_encode($data, TRUE));`
```

Comment: When it's a string, you can echo. When it has been an object, use var_dump(). Instead of echo you can use print_r().